# Spring CSRF Mutltipart File Upload

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I followed this guide:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

to setup a file upload on my spring mvc project but I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid CSRF Token &#39;null&#39; was found on the request parameter &#39;_csrf&#39; or header &#39;X-CSRF-TOKEN&#39;.
```

My web.xml (full)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>1000000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>1000000</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>10000</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-datasource.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <!-- Spring Security  Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Spring servlet content (full)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.at.ccts.controller" />

 </beans:beans>
```

jsp

```
        <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
    <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create/form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // store the bytes somewhere
       return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
   } else {
       return "redirect:uploadFailure";
   }
}
```

Anyone has any ideas as to why it still asking for token?

Comment: Have you tried the Spring form taglib?

Comment: Changed form to form:form fixed the issue.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security by default now requires CSRF tokens on all "modifying" requests (POST, DELETE, etc.). To make dealing with CSRF easier, you can use the Spring taglibs (for JSP) or the Spring Security dialect (for Thymeleaf). For JSP, you'd simply write your form as

```
<form:form ...>
```

and the taglib will insert an `<input type="hidden">` with the CSRF token for you.